# Sum of columns from the same file

Tags: python, sum, spyder

I need to calculate a moment *(Mz,correct)* given by the sum of a moment *(Mz)* and a force *(Fx)* multiplied by its arm *(300.56)* because I need to make a change of reference system and mobilize everything on the new system of reference. This is the script I tried to write that Fx and Mz the same starting file (.dat):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-----------------------input file-------------------------------
filename = 'drag_time_series' #nome file sorgente
# specifica percorso file DAT
df = pd.read_csv(rf"C:\Users\suemack528\Desktop\OneDrive - Università degli Studi di Padova\deme\unipd\magistrale\TESI\impalcato\drag\{filename}.dat",
                 header=1, delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.round(decimals=3)

#-----for "cycle" to obtain correct moment-----
for i in range(len('Mz')):
    Mz,correct[i]=df('Mz') + df('Fx')*300.56
```

I think that is not correct. How can I write this script better? I'm doing it with spyder

[error obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ne65.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get a column from a pandas dataframe you can use `[]` (instead of `()`). For more information regarding the use of indexes and selecting data from a dataframe you can check the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics